# supremum of brownian motion almost surely > 0

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Is it true that
\begin{equation}
M_t = \sup_{s \leq t} B_s > 0 \ \ \text{a.s.}
\end{equation}
for all $t>0$? I remember reading this somewhere, but intuitively, can't the Brownian motion B stay below 0 for some time with probability $>0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Blumenthal zero one law?

Comment: I have heard of it and I just checked on Wikipedia. Does that really explain the above?

Comment: Yes, you can argue using that. Another way to see it is if you know that $tB_{1/t}$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: @clark Could you elaborate how I can use the fact that $tB_{1/t}$ is a BM?

Comment: Since $B_t$ as $t\to \infty$ cannot stay always positive, it means that $tB_{1/t}$ must be alternating sign as $t\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to argue is using Blumenthal's zero one law. Define $A_n=\{B_{1/n}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\}$, and set $B=\{B_{1/n}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ~\text{i.o.}\} $

Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(B) &=\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n A_n)\\
&\geq \limsup_n\mathbb{P}( A_n)\\
&= \limsup_n\mathbb{P}(B_{1/n}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\\
&=\limsup_n\mathbb{P}(N(0,1)>1)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(N(0,1)>1)=M>0
\end{align*}

By Blumenthal's zero one law $\mathbb{P}(B)= 1 ~\text{or}~0$. So $\mathbb{P}(B)=1$.